# What does Lock services in Azure Pipelines' task DockerCompose actually do?

Tags: docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am learning to use `Azure Pipelines` for CI/CD. I read the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops#lock-service-images) and found the `Docker Compose` task has an action called `Lock services`. I have no idea what this action actually do and what it means by locking the images.

Can anyone explain it to me, or provide me some examples on when and how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*We have public the source code of this task, so you can check this [page](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DockerComposeV0/dockercomposelock.ts) to analyze what the exactly action this command do.*

For image, there has 2 different identifies: `tag` and `digest`. Now, let's assume one scenario:

Most of time, a tagged image in Container Registry is **mutable**, so with appropriate permissions you or anyone can update/push/delete an image with the same tag to that registry. **However**, when you deploy a image to production env, you could not sure whether the image with one specific tag does not been overwritten and it is the one you want to deployed.

At this time, `digest` would be a best choice for you.

Because `digest` is a **SHA256** calculated from the image and identifies it **uniquely**. Once there has any changes to your image, the corresponding `SHA256 value` will be changes also.

---

**Explanation** of this action:

Check this [code line](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DockerComposeV0/dockercomposelock.ts#L13)(defined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/2113087249b52b2dd6a30700666e1ec797c83253/Tasks/DockerComposeV0/dockercomposedigests.ts#L46)). It's work logic is read out the image(s) used in the `docker-compose.yml` file, pull image(s) and generate a digest for them. Next a new `docker-compose.yml` file is automatically generated, which the image will be specified with digest in this new `docker-compose.yml` file.

---

**Sample**:

The task definition i used:

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Lock services'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryEndpoint: {service connection name}
    dockerComposeFile: 'Docker/docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Lock services'
    removeBuildOptions: true
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: xxxx/testwebapp
    ports:
      - "1983:80"
  newsfeed:
    image: xxx/merlin
  redis:
    image: redis
```

See the build `log` of this task:

[image]

And the contents of `new docker-compose.yml` which generated.

*(List them by using `cat xxx` command)*:

[image]

---

Now, when you deploy the images to production, just use the new `docker-compose.yml` file the task generated automatically. This can guarantee the deployed image is the version you built at the beginning, even if someone overwrites this image later.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Sorry that I did not know the source code is available on GitHub and had not read by myself.

Comment: @MangoWong it’s never late to know this source code  It is much help on documents understanding!

Comment: This information would be great in the docs, I was not at all clear what the feature did either until I read your explanation here. Thanks for the explainer, example, and the links.